# How to use all with a monadic function?

Tags: list, haskell, monads

I have found myself in a situation where I want to use `all` with a monadic function. In my mind this didn't really turn out too pretty:

```
f :: Monad m => a -> m Bool

g :: Monad m => [a] -> m Int
g xs = do cnd <- liftM (all (== True)) $ mapM f xs
          if cnd
           then return 42
           else return 0
```

Is there a Better™ way to do this?

Comment: First of all, you don't want to use `all (== True)` but `and` :-)

Comment: Indeed, more generally: equality comparison on booleans is almost always needless. If it wasn't for `and`, you could still just write `all id`.

Comment: Your implementation does not "short-circuit" correctly: while the pure computation short-circuits, it must run all the side effects first. See [`andM`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/monad-loops-0.4.2.1/docs/Control-Monad-Loops.html) from the monad-loops package (and its brother, `allM`) for a version that only does as many side-effects as necessary to know the answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you `import Control.Applicative` and `Data.Bool` (if using `base >= 4.7`), then you could write it as

```
g xs = bool 0 42 <$> and <$> mapM f xs
-- Or equivalently
-- g xs = bool 0 42 . and <$> mapM f xs
-- g = fmap (bool 0 42 . and) . mapM f
```

But I don't think this gains you a whole lot.  Instead, you could also pull that `return` outside the `if-then-else`:

```
g xs = do cnd <- and <$> mapM f xs
          return $ if cnd then 42 else 0
```

Or even

```
g xs = do ys <- mapM f xs
          return $ if and ys then 42 else 0
```

I think one of the last two versions is what most people would be more comfortable seeing, although the last one just looks a bit weird for English speakers with the "if and foo then bar else baz"

Comment: While you introduce `Control.Applicative`: it's worth noting that the function doesn't seem to need the `Monad` constraint – `Applicative` is sufficient for what `g` does (with [`traverse`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.2/docs/Data-Traversable.html#v:traverse) instead of `mapM`). So even if `f` needs `Monad`, it's better to keep the operators in `g` on that more basic level.

Comment: @leftaroundabout The monad constraint comes from `f` rather than `mapM`.  It could be that `f`'s constraint could be relaxed to `Applicative f => a -> f Bool`, but that's unknown at this time.

Comment: `and <$> mapM f xs` was really what I was looking for, great!

Comment: +1 for the `bool` function, but I think `bool 0 42 <$> and <$> mapM f xs` is really confusing as it uses `<$>` over two different Functor instances.

Comment: @Bergi What two functor instances?  It's the same functor instance, since it can also be represented as `bool 0 42 . and <$> mapM f xs` using the functor law `fmap f . fmap g = fmap (f . g)`, unless I'm mistaken and this is parsed as `(bool 0 42 <$> and) <$> mapM f xs`, but in that case the `<$>` gets specialized to `.` anyway, giving it the same equational meaning.

Comment: Yes, `<$>` is left-associative so this is parsed `(bool 0 42 <$> and) <$> mapM f xs`. And the first `<$>` is specialised to `.`, while the second is specialised to `liftM`!

Comment: @Bergi Gotcha.  Still, you can transform between the two using equational reasoning pretty easily, but it does use both functor instances the way I've written it.  I honestly don't mind the style since it just looks like you're just replacing `$` with `<$>`.

Answer (score 5):

If you are already using `do`-notation, I wouldn't bother with `liftM` at all. Just go for

```
g xs = do cnds <- mapM f xs
          return $ if and cnds
                     then 42
                     else 0
```

---

Alternatively, if you want a lazy `all` that does not run all of the monads, I think you'll need to write it your own.

```
allM f xs = foldr (\x acc -> do b <- f x; if b then return True else acc) (return True) xs

g = fmap (\cnd -> if cnd then 42 else 0) . allM f

-- much nicer with `bool`:

allM f = foldr (\x acc -> f x >>= bool (return True) acc) (return True)
g = fmap (bool 42 0) . allM f
```